# WordPress extra categories are showing on blog page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following code

```
<?php  
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        query_posts(array(
        'post_type'      => 'post', // You can add a custom post type if you like
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'cat_id'=> 5,   
    ));
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

I want to show category whose id is 5 on my bog page. But this is showing other categories as well like 4 & 3.
Similarity issue is for archive page as well. Where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

this is working at my end

Comment: i still not able to get your point what is offset here? i have modified my query post adding offset but its still not working for me...

Comment: both querys are working at my end.. you need to check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

check this, i think this is helpful for you.

```
  <?php 
$posts = get_posts('category=5&orderby=rand&numberposts=5'); 
foreach($posts as $post) { 
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$args3 = array(
                        'numberposts' => 1,
                        'cat' => 5,
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_parent' => '',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'suppress_filters' => true
                    );

                    $homepage_post = get_posts($args3);
                    foreach ($homepage_post as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

                    // write your code here ...  

                    endforeach;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
```

--
Thanks